# Can't access XAMPP on Centos from other Windows PCs

Tags: networking, centos, xampp

I have a server with Centos 6 on it and I have installed XAMPP on it. I have this server on static IP address.

But I can't access this server's IP address from other PCs. I tried to access XAMPP on another PC with a static IP address with Windows OS, and it works perfectly. Even accessing it from the server itself and it's open.

But I can't access the server IP from any other PC. I can ping the server. I can access SSH using Putty on the server and login. But I can't open the localhost of the server from any other computer on the network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it could be your firewall. The default firewall of CentOS permits ssh input(tcp 22) and icmp(ping)

```
[root@ ~]# cat /etc/sysconfig/iptables
# Firewall configuration written by system-config-firewall
# Manual customization of this file is not recommended.
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
COMMIT
```

Try at first stopping your firewall issuing the following command:

```
[root@ ~]# /etc/init.d/iptables stop
```

Now, test if you can access your XAMPP server

---

After that, it could be a good catch to enable just the ports you need to access(80 or 443, or both):

80(www)

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

443(https)

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
```

both:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j ACCEPT
```